# Putting Elements side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put these two elements side by side. I tried using the float: right or float left, but so far no luck. Here is my html code.

```css
    #idd11 {

      float: left;

      width 100px;

      height 100px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm" id="idd11" style="display: block">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-9 col-xxs-9">
    <div class="fh5co-project-item to-animate">
      <div class="fh5co-text">
        <span><br></span>
        <h2 align="center">Items List</h2>
        <span><br></span>
        <div id="MainMenu">
          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#item1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default strong item1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">
                                Item 1
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="item1"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#item2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default strong item2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">
                                Item 2
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="item2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 id="answer">Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Answer A-->
    <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm" id="floating" style="display: block">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-3 col-xxs-3">
        <div class="fh5co-project-item to-animate">
          <div class="fh5co-text">
            <span><br></span>
            <div id="MainMenu">
              <h1 id="newAnswer">A</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Answer A-->
  </div>
</div>
```

If anybody can help me with it, it would be greatly appreciated. I tried at least :p. I attached a screenshot too: I want to put the A element in the right side of the Items list.

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: You are trying to float only one `div` here. The main `div` with the id of `idd11`. You need more than one div and another div to hold them in order to float them next to each other.

Comment: You are only floating the  #idd11 div left, you also have to float the #floating div right

Comment: I tried with both left and right, and doesnt work

Comment: Upon closer inspection, your mistake seems not to be a floating issue, but a formatting issue. Take a look at my answer to see an explaination.

Comment: @Jimenemex I got it bro thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three divs to do this. One div to hold the other two child divs. Then float the two child divs next to each other. So put the things you want floated next to each other inside a div and try to float them.

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child1'>
       ...
    </div> <!-- End child1 div -->
    <div id='child2'>
       ...
    </div> <!-- End child2 div -->
 </div> <!-- End parent div -->
```

CSS

```
#parent{
    width: 500px;
}
#child1{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
#child2{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
```

In your code, you have the div you are trying to `float` to the right within the div you are trying to `float` to the left. You need to make sure your `divs` are separated and put into a parent `div`. Take a look at my example and notice how my `divs` are separate from each other, but inside a parent `div`

```
<div id='parent'> <!-- Look here -->
<div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm" id="idd11" style="display: block">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-9 col-xxs-9">
    <div class="fh5co-project-item to-animate">
      <div class="fh5co-text">
        <span><br></span>
        <h2 align="center">Items List</h2>
        <span><br></span>
        <div id="MainMenu">
          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#item1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default strong item1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">
                                Item 1
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="item1"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#item2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default strong item2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">
                                Item 2
                                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="item2"></div>
          </div>

        <h2 id="answer">Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End the floating left section -->
    <!--Answer A-->
    <div class="row row-bottom-padded-sm" id="floating" style="display: block">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-3 col-xxs-3">
        <div class="fh5co-project-item to-animate">
          <div class="fh5co-text">
            <span><br></span>
            <div id="MainMenu">
              <h1 id="newAnswer">A</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End the floating right Section -->
    <!--Answer A-->

</div> <!-- End parent div -->
```

Comment: I tried this, but whenever i apply the float:right to the second child(in my case id="floating") , it just disappears.

Comment: Try to make their widths lower then 50% of the parent div. Sometimes when it's 50% they tend to get pushed around. Or you can look into the `overflow` property. That specifies what to do when they escape their bounds. I'll update my answer

Comment: I tried it i even added the width, but still it disappears, i am not sure what i am doing wrong. I separated the children and put them under one parent.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` for the `id="MainMenu"` . you can then adjust the width and height for its child elements too..
Try learning more about css3 flexbox property